# Google Pay(Tez) Integration into my payment gateway ? (Android)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-pay, google-tez

**Note :** I am aware it is not yet available for iOS, Also i am not looking for Xamarin.Forms(Obviously).

Been trying to integrate `Google Pay(Tez)` API into my `Xamarin` Application when I realised that there are no guides available for its integration to `Xamarin` which is fine.

So, I visited the [Google Pay API](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/tutorial) page, Which seems to have a sweet looking guide for `Android(Java)` so I started converting the native Android code into `Xamarin`. And then I hit a bump where the [PaymentsClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/PaymentsClient) class seems to be unavailable in Xamarin, So I tried checking for its namespace so maybe I could understand if it was available or not(`Xamarin.Android`). But there is no mention of the namespace of this class(None that I noticed). All I could find in its info is that it inherits from `com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi` which did not help at all actually.

**Queries**

- Am I missing some package here or is there some alternative that is used in `Xamarin`?
- Is There some guide to integrating Google pay(Tez) API for `Xamarin` apps that I have missed?
- Is Google pay(Tez) integration not added in Xamarin.Android yet?
- Or is there something wrong with my current config? i.e `VS17 Pro` version `15.6.7` , `Xamarin` version `4.9.0.753` and `Xamarin.Android` version `8.2.0.16` Android SDK latest with all the API versions above v 4.0

Comment: Are you trying to integrate Tez or Google Pay as you are asking about Google Tez but referring to the Google Pay API via links/docs. If you are talking about Tez, are you looking for Tez integration via the payment intent, the comm API or the Web api?

Comment: @SushiHangover The name of Google Tez officially is [Google Pay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.user&hl=en_IN) now that is why I referred it to as Google Pay. I am looking for Tez integration via payment intent, What is a comm API by the way?

Comment: Technically "Google Pay" and "Google Pay for India" are two totally different things. Personally a really bad name choice for a Tez rebranding as Tez is UPI based and Google Pay/Wallet is not and every time I am asking India based? or not? as I have to implement multiple payment systems in the app... 

Comment: See my updated answer.... The communication API is setup to allow messages to be sent from merchants that a user has bought something, so things like taxi, hotels, food, rent/phone/car payments notifications, your payment receipts, etc.. can be sent... this is an India only feature of "Tez"

Comment: @SushiHangover Trust me I have been in your shoes I used to call it Tez too and then people started telling how it is now google pay. In any case, I just wanted to confirm something that is the Xamarin.Android equivalent for this : `IsReadyToPayRequest request = IsReadyToPayRequest.fromJson(GooglePayUtility.GetIsReadyToPayRequest().ToString());` this in particular `IsReadyToPayRequest.fromJson`

Comment: I did check it I am working on this right now as soon as I see it work I will let you know and also will mark the answer!

Comment: FYI: The code in that comment is Google Pay (non-India) based, not Tez based.

Comment: @SushiHangover Oh, don't worry I know that it is for something else I mean the same app for outside India Google PAY!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Google Pay (not Tez):

```
Package: `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Wallet`
```

Make sure that you enable your app for Wallet processing via the `metadata` in the manifest, or via your application's `MetaDataAttribute`:

```
[Application]
[MetaData(name: "com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled", Value = "true")]
```

From there it is a matter of `using Android.Gms.Wallet;` and setting up and using the `PaymentsClient`, ie.

```
PaymentsClient paymentsClient = WalletClass.GetPaymentsClient(
        this, 
        new WalletClass.WalletOptions.Builder()
                .SetEnvironment(WalletConstants.EnvironmentTest)
                .Build()
);
```

#### Google Pay for India (UPI Intent-based):

To pass the transaction information to "Tez", you define an URI that includes all of your merchant information, transaction amount, etc... This URI is based upon the UNIFIED PAYMENTS INTERFACE `UPI` scheme (this is not controlled by Google and thus you have refer to UPI specs for what data you need to pass).

re: https://www.npci.org.in/sites/all/themes/npcl/images/PDF/UPI_Linking_Specs_ver_1.5.1.pdf

```
using (var uri = new Android.Net.Uri.Builder()
        .Scheme("upi")
        .Authority("pay")
        .AppendQueryParameter("pa", "your-merchant-vpa@xxx")
        .AppendQueryParameter("pn", "your-merchant-name")
        .AppendQueryParameter("mc", "your-merchant-code")
        .AppendQueryParameter("tr", "your-transaction-ref-id")
        .AppendQueryParameter("tn", "your-transaction-note")
        .AppendQueryParameter("am", "your-order-amount")
        .AppendQueryParameter("cu", "INR")
        .AppendQueryParameter("url", "your-transaction-url")
        .Build())
{
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
    intent.SetData(uri);
    intent.SetPackage("com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.user");
    StartActivityForResult(intent, 9999);
}
```

Then of course you would implement an override for `OnActivityResult` and process the result:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 9999)
    {
        Log.Debug("tez result", data.GetStringExtra("Status"));
    }
}
```